# How to set a root directory include different cmake packages with the highest priority for find_package

Tags: cmake

I have a series of libraries that I want to put in the same custom directory for find_package to find.like:

```
custom_root_dir
  -include
    -libA
    -libB
  -bin
    -libA
    -libB
  -lib
    -libA
    -libB
  -share
    -libA
       -libAConfig.cmake
    -libB
       -libBCOnfig.cmake
```

or

```
custom_root_dir
    -libA
       -include
       -lib
       -bin
       -share
         -libAConfig.cmake
    -libB
```

Now I use the set(_DIR) method

CMakeLists.txt of libA

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX <custom_root_dir> CACHE PATH "custom install directory")
...
install(EXPORT ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  FILE ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake
  NAMESPACE ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}::
  DESTINATION /share/libA
)
...
```

CMakeLists.txt of app

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX <custom_root_dir> CACHE PATH "custom install directory")
set(libA_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/libA))
find_package(libA)
set(libB_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/libB))
find_package(libB)
set(libC_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/libC))
find_package(libC)
```

This method results in me needing to write set(_Dir) many times.Is there any way to achieve this： Only set custom_root_dir once at first in each cmake package and find_package will always find packages there.